# TeamViewer SendMessage() avoidance?

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I'm trying to make a program which interacts with another program (as a form of addon, if you will) without any interface other than a GUI which I'm "hacking" away at. The method I'm using is the SendMessage() function.

The issue I'm confronted with is that TeamViewer somehow blocks this function, so I can't access the program itself. I believe this is related to the button which TeamViewer adds to the top of windows (the button allowing the user to "share this application with other computers").

I'm sure there must be some parameter I can pass to send it to the actual main window of the process I'm interacting with... I'm just not sure of where to begin looking.

The function I'm using to send the message looks like this:

```
    public void SendButton(string Key)
    {
        IntPtr wParam = new IntPtr(getKeyCode(Key));
        SendMessage(Util.Handle, Constants.WM_KEYDOWN, wParam, new IntPtr(0));
        SendMessage(Util.Handle, Constants.WM_KEYUP, wParam, new IntPtr(0));
    }
```

Thanks

P.S I should point out at this point that my software is working fine without TeamViewer running, but as soon as I run it it stops working. I am "friendly" with several people who develop similar software, most of whom have encountered this exact issue, and they claim there is a very easy workaround... Unfortunately I can't find it.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do? are you sure you use correct handle, class, etc for the teamviewer window?
how are you searching details for a window?

Comment: For the window itself I'm acquiring information using Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad.exe");

I'm trying to send letters to the notepad window, using a function like:

        public void SendButton(string Key)
        {
            IntPtr wParam = new IntPtr(getKeyCode(Key));
            SendMessage(Util.Handle, Constants.WM_KEYDOWN, wParam, new IntPtr(0));
            SendMessage(Util.Handle, Constants.WM_KEYUP, wParam, new IntPtr(0));
        }

Where Key is 0x70 (for F1) etc~~

Comment: So is it working for you for 'notepad.exe'? Is it sending some keys to the notepad window? Or it is not even working for notepad window?

Comment: It works when I don't have TeamViewer running, but I think TeamViewer sets the MainWindow to the wrong one, not sure exactly what's going on with it. The keys get sent fine to Notepad without TV running, as soon as I start it it doesn't work, and once I close it again it does...

Comment: is notepad windows in focus, active? when TeamViewer is started?

Comment: I've not got notepad in focus, but it shouldn't require it... The function I'm using works below the input level, and is now in the main post above...

Comment: try to take handle every time you need a handle, what will happen? put getting handle in a method. It shouldn't change the handle, but try to.

Comment: I get the handle dynamically on startup of my program, so there is no risk of the handle changing by that logic... Is it possible that two apps can't access the same process at the same time? Note I've tried running my app when TeamViewer is already running, too...

Comment: Also I just found that in TeamViewer if you go to Options > Advanced Options, configure the "QuickConnect" button and disable it for the window you're attempting to manipulate, the issue stops, as well, so it does appear that somehow TeamViewer is modifying the window in some definition of a "non standard fashion"...

Comment: Sorry for the multiple responses but I thought I might also point out that the handle doesn't appear to change (that I can see), I've only tested it lightly though. I've now implemented another piece of code which will switch between two notepad windows based on their contents (memory reading, such fun in C#!) and the results demonstrate the same thing, switching windows doesn't grab a correct handle any better than launching from scratch. As long as the QuickConnect button is enabled, the issue persists...